# Retornar a mesma URL e mudar o Label aspx asp.net

Tags: asp.net, url

Estou fazendo uma validação em um sistema de vendas, onde se o vendedor clicar em um cliente que está com débitos o acesso não é permitido. Até ai sem problemas, fiz a conexão com o *DB* e a validação.

Gostaria que quando esse cenário acontecesse, o usuário permanecesse na mesma página e o sistema mudasse o valor de um *Label*.
Já fiz o código para alterar o valor do *Label*, porém não sei como permaneço na mesma página, pois ao utilizar o `response.Request`, o sistema **volta a página inicial** de clientes

O sistema utiliza o **asp.net 2.0**

Comment: Thiago, forneça mais detalhes, sua pergunta está muito aberta. Seria interessante também colocar a parte do código onde você está com dificuldades.

Answer (score 1):

O controle que inicializa o evento pode ter a propriedade `AutoPostBack=True`
isso significa que um evento nele irá provocar um reenvio da página

mas pode-se controlar para atualizar apenas a parte que tu quer
daí tu utiliza o componente `"UpdatePanel"` pra isso
e tem que ter também o `"ScriptManager"` pra poder fazer isto